# Why do my macarons come out looking weird?

Tags: baking, macarons

Recipe I use:

100g grade AA brown large egg white

50g sugar

200g confectioners sugar

110g almond flour (I grind my almond flour using nutribullet)

5g egg white powder

1/4 teaspoon cream of tartar

I use a kitchen aid to beat the egg white gradually, starting at speed 4, after about 3 mins I added the sugar and egg white powder mixture slowly. I increase the speed to six, beat for another 3 mins, then increase to 8 for another 2 mins, and speed 10 for 1mins. So the total beating time is about 9 mins.

Then I fold in the almond flour and confectioners sugar mixture(sifted) gradually. When it's ready, I pipe them in a size about 1.25 inch space in-between 3 quarters to 1 inch. Then I let them rest for about 30 mins until the surface is not sticky. I baked them in a whirlpool conventional oven for about 11 mins at temperature 285 Fahrenheit. They came out looking like the picture below. Please help! What did I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've seen worse macarons than that! Just to be clear, are you unhappy with them because they are a little uneven?

Comment: Agreed. They look great to me. I too assume the OP is looking for perfectly level macaroons.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, macarons. If it's not one thing, it's another. Uneven *pied* usually indicate that the oven was too hot. You should use an oven thermometer to determine the exact temperature of your oven, because oven dials themselves straight up lie. I once had an oven that was always 20C *over* the temperature on the dial.

If you get a thermometer (or have one) and this still happens, try positioning the tray at different heights in the oven.

Unfortunately, making macarons is a process of trial, error and experience, getting to know your oven and the texture of the batter. Good luck.

Comment: Couldn't it be air bubbles? Isn't there advice to drop the tray onto a surface from 6-9 inches up?

Comment: Possibly, but you'd normally see more pitting on the top in that situation.

Comment: That's good to know. I've never made them myself although I plan to try, so all information is helpful.

Comment: They are tricky because there are so many variables. Treat it like a scientific experiment and you will eventually prevail!